# Select Combobox Value Based on Textbox.Text

Tags: vb.net, combobox

I have a 'Drop Down' style combobox named EmployedCombobox1. I am trying to have EmployedComobox1 automatically select a value depending on the text that is written in a textbox located on another form.

The code below is how my EmployedCombobox is populated:

```
Private Sub getinstitutionname(ByVal p_institution1_id As Integer)
    If sConnection.State = ConnectionState.Closed Then
        sConnection.ConnectionString = Search.sqlConnect
        sConnection.Open()
    End If

    Dim sqlAdapter As New MySqlDataAdapter
    Dim sqlCommand As New MySqlCommand
    Dim sqlTable As New DataTable
    Dim InstitutionName As String

    Dim sqlText As String = "select * from institution order by institution_name"
    Dim InstitutionID As Integer
    With sqlCommand
        .CommandText = sqlText
        .Connection = sConnection
    End With

    With sqlAdapter
        .SelectCommand = sqlCommand
        .Fill(sqlTable)
    End With

    EmployedComboBox1.Items.Clear()
    EmployedComboBox1.SelectedIndex = -1

    For i = 0 To sqlTable.Rows.Count - 1
        InstitutionName = sqlTable.Rows(i)("institution_name")
        InstitutionID = sqlTable.Rows(i)("institution_id")
        EmployedComboBox1.Items.Add(InstitutionName)
        If p_institution1_id = InstitutionID Then
            EmployedComboBox1.SelectedIndex = i
        End If
    Next
    sqlTable.Dispose()
    sqlCommand.Dispose()
    sqlAdapter.Dispose()
```

Next, the code below is me attempting to auto select the value based off a textbox.text:

```
    Dim sqlAdapter1 As New MySqlDataAdapter
    Dim sqlCommand1 As New MySqlCommand
    Dim sqlTable1 As New DataTable

    Dim sqlText1 As String = "select institution_name from institution where institution_name='" & Institution.InstitutionNameTextBox.Text & "'"

    If Search.debugging = True Then
        MsgBox(sqlText1)
    End If

    With sqlCommand1
        .CommandText = sqlText1
        .Connection = sConnection
    End With

    With sqlAdapter1
        .SelectCommand = sqlCommand1
        .Fill(sqlTable1)
    End With

    For i = 0 To sqlTable1.Rows.Count - 1
        Me.EmployedComboBox1.SelectedItem = (sqlTable1.Rows(i)("institution_name"))
    Next
    sqlTable1.Dispose()
    sqlCommand1.Dispose()
    sqlAdapter1.Dispose()
```

When I run that second code, nothing gets selected in the combobox when there is text written in the Textbox.

Comment: This line bothers me. I would instead make a string first to make sure it's within the items of the combo first:

Comment: Do something like Dim y = (sqlTable1.Rows(i)("institution_name")).

Comment: That will give me an error stating "Conversion from string to type integer not valid"

Comment: Did you set y to a string when the sql line is a integer or vice versa? That's probably your problem elsewhere. "(sqlTable1.Rows(i)("institution_name"))." isn't the same type of variable as combobox.selecteditem. Try selected index or casting it.

Comment: What do you write in the textbox ?? the same as the combo box item ??

Comment: Yes. So lets say "Xyz." is written in the textbox, the combobox should have a value that to select that states "Xyz." All values are coming from a table in my database. so everything will match.

Answer (score 0):

like you say the values are the same so i would make a AutoCompleteStringCollection for the text box.

And on page load put the items that are in combo box also in the AutoCompleteStringCollection."or after you load you're combo box"
Then add it to the text box

Then for the selecting i would use AutoCompleteMode.Suggest otherwise it will select a item in the combo box if you type 1 letter in the text box.

```
Dim names As New AutoCompleteStringCollection()

Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
    ComboBox1.Items.AddRange({"yes", "no", "mmm"})

    For Each item As String In ComboBox1.Items
        names.Add(item)
    Next

    With TextBox1
        .AutoCompleteMode = AutoCompleteMode.Suggest
        .AutoCompleteCustomSource = names
        .AutoCompleteSource = AutoCompleteSource.CustomSource
    End With
End Sub
```

For the selecting of the combo box item , first check if the text box text exists in the combo box and then select it."like the code shows below"
i used TextBox1_TextChanged event for it.

```
Private Sub TextBox1_TextChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles TextBox1.TextChanged
    If ComboBox1.Items.Contains(TextBox1.Text) = True Then
        ComboBox1.SelectedIndex = (ComboBox1.FindString(TextBox1.Text))
    End If
End Sub
```